# How to force my output data in a inputdlg on Matlab be a double?

Tags: matlab, typeconverter

I'm currently using a MATLAB to work and I need some help:

I need to convert my output data (variable: units) be a double instead of a cell because I must perform a sum:

```
units = inputdlg(question,title);
sum = units + i;
```

I've tried this code also but didn't solve my problem:

```
units = double(inputdlg(question,title));
sum = units + i;
```

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`inputdlg`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html) returns a cell array of strings. You can convert to `double` with `str2double`:

```
units = str2double(inputdlg(question, title));
```